# Rhino: Access Java interface variables in Javascript implementation

Tags: java, javascript, interface, rhino

Rhino: How to access Java interface variables in Javascript implementation?

I expose a java interface for some other party to let them provide an implementation for the same in javascript.

```
public interface APIInterface{

    public static APIUtils util = new APIUtils();

    public ArrayList getAllObjects(Object aTransaction);
}
```

Javascript implementation:

```
/** Core Interface Method **/
new Object() {

  getAllObjects: function(tran) {
        tran.set(..); //OK  
        tran.set(..); //OK
        util.callSomeFunction(); //Fails here..Rhino doesn't understand util.. 
  }    

}
```

I want the javascript implementation of the interface to understand the interface variable `util` without having to pass it as an additional argument to the function or by adding it to the `ScriptEngine`. Is this technically possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the interface...

```
package foo;
public interface Iface {
  String X = "Hello, World!";
  void invoke();
}
```

...static member¹ `X` can be accessed two ways.

1) Via the type:

```
var x = Packages.foo.Iface.X;
```

2) Via reflection:

```
var impl = new Packages.foo.Iface({
  invoke : function () {
    var x = this.getClass().getField("X").get(null);
    java.lang.System.out.println(x);
  }
});
impl.invoke();
```

Tested on Rhino 1.7R4.

*¹All variables are implicitly `public static final` on interfaces.*