# Calling java class methods in Rhino script

Tags: java, rhino

I have one interface method as follows and saved in Order.java file
and rhino script.

In rhino script I am trying to call the interface methods.

**rhino:**

```
var x = Packages.com.data.Order.X;
print(x);
```

**java:**

```
package com.data;

public interface Order 
{
    String X = "Hello, World!";
    void invoke();
}
```

but it is not printing "Hello world".

Instead it is printing

> uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: Cannot call
>   property invoke in object [JavaPackage com.data.Order]. It is not a
>   function, it is "object". "

**problem Statement: How to call java interface method from rhino script.**

Comment: you can refer link  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580164/rhino-access-java-interface-variables-in-javascript-implementation

Comment: Hi Afgan I referred the above link. Bu still same  issue

Comment: can you please update with full stack trace of exception ?

Comment: Script:    
var x =Packages.com.data.Order.X;
print(x);                                                                                                                              output :[JavaPackage com.data.Order.X]                                                                       Expected: Hello world

Comment: @Arundhati, try to add import statement like import com.data.Order package in script, and then  write this code without Packages specification like  - var x = com.data.Order.X;
print(x);

Comment: import com.data.Order  is not the correct syntax seems in Js.                                    I tried with var d = importPackage(com.data.Order); print(d.X);                                   but error is 
js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: Cannot read property "X" from undefined

Comment: I think you are writing this code in rhino, not in JS, as far as i know we can able to give package specification on top of file as we can do in java class. Have you tried out this way ?

Comment: I specified I writing rhino script. ya I tried specifying package on top. but same error.              I tried following also                                                                       var t = Packages.Example.foo();
print(t);                                                                                                                  where Example is a class ,foo is  a method in that class,   But getting error "js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: Cannot call property foo in object [JavaPackage Example]. It is not a function, it is "object".

Comment: Please tell me how you are running your rhino script ?

Comment: I am running it in eclipse. I followed below URL to run rhino script in eclipse   http://martin-toshev.com/index.php/software-engineering/tips-and-tricks/76-running-javascript-from-eclipse

Comment: Please add this line in your Argument field and try to run  -  java -cp /path/to/rhino/js.jar:. org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main

Comment: no effect @Afgan

Comment: jar -js ${resource_loc} add fully qualified path of your JS file at the place of ${resource_loc} like- >  jar -js com.myjs.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165282/discussion-between-afgan-and-arundhathi-d).

Answer (score 0):

That type of error usually means that the Rhino engine is not seeing the class you are attempting to use.

If you are definitely seeing the jar get into the classpath, next, I'd double check that the jar contains your class exactly as referenced.

You can verify whether the JS step is seeing your class properly by Alerting it like this:

Alert(com.foo.bar.MyClass);

If the Alert indicates it is a JavaClass then it found your class. Otherwise it will say it is a JavaPackage.